# Datatables Editor set radio value to data

Tags: php, jquery-datatables-editor

I'm using Datatables Editor & Server Side to display a large table of data.  However, I have a custom edit form that I want to use.   To get to that edit form, I have a radio button on each item.   My challenge is that I want to set the value of the radio button to be the modelID from one of the tables.

Here is what I have so far:

```
var editor; // use a global for the submit and return data rendering in the examples

$(document).ready(function() {
editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
    ajax: "../php/test.php",
    table: "#example",
    fields: [ {
            label: "Mfg ID",
            name:  "ball_mfg.mfgID"
        }, {
            label: "Mfg name:",
            name:  "ball_mfg.name"
        }, {
            label: "Model #",
            name:  "ball_model.modelID"
        }, {
            label: "Model Name:",
            name:  "ball_model.name"
        }
    ]
} );

$('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: "Bfrtip",
    ajax: {
        url: "../php/test.php",
        type: 'POST'
    },
    columns: [
        { "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
            return '<input type="radio" name="select_model" class="radio1 my_input" value="1">';
        }},  // here's a radio button, modify to use data to populate it,
        { data: "ball_mfg.name" },
        { data: "ball_model.name" }
    ],
    select: false,
    buttons: [
    ]
} );
```

I need the value="1" to be the contents of field ball_model.modelID.

Answer (score 0):

OK.. I found the solution.

Change this:

```
            return '<input type="radio" name="select_model" class="radio1 my_input" value="1">';
```

To this:

```
            return '<input type="radio" name="select_model" class="radio1 my_input" value="'+full.ball_model.modelID+'">';
```